# Using a power series method for proof of solution to first order matrix ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

$$y' = A y$$

show the given solution to the ODE is of the form:

$$ e^{Ax}C=y(x)$$

I know how to use this equation, and have used it many times by applying the definition of a matrix exponential as well as Jordan normal forms in order to have an explicit solution. However, the derivation using power series solutions I have no idea where to start.

$\mathtt{Ideas:}$

$$ \mathtt{ansatz:} \sum_0^{\infty} (A_n x)^n = y(x)$$
where each term $A_n$ is a matrix??

Comment: $$
\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx} e^{Ax} = Ae^{Ax}
$$

Comment: I don't think this is relevant at all to my question asked. It comes across as just a useless remark that everyone already knows. Before answering questions so hastily to appear smart, try reading them fully and making the community better. Not worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initial condition: $y(0)=y_0$. I shall use $t$ instead of $x$ as the independent variable. We may first assume there exists a solution $y$ that is infinitely differentiable.

Then,
$$
y'(0)=Ay_0,y''(0)=A^2 y_0,\ldots, y^{(n)}(0)=A^n y_0,
$$
by repeatedly differentiating with respect to $t$. (You seem to mean that $A$ is constant.)

The Taylor series expansion of $y(t)$ at $t=0$ is, therefore
$$
y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(A^n y_0) t^n}{n!}=\exp(tA) y_0.
$$
I have ignored the issue of convergence here - but it is very easy to see why it converges, and once we know it converges, it is a direct computation that $y$ does satisfy the differential equation. The solution is, indeed unique by a theorem of ODE (see Existence and uniqueness theorem). Therefore, **all solutions to this DE is infinitely differentiable.**

Comment: It is not given that $y$ is infinitely differentiable...

Comment: @Math1000 The aim is to find a solution - so you can make any assumption about the solution you are going to find; it is not a proof, but a way of reaching the answer.